# Mono Framework vs .Net

Tags: c#, mono, visual-studio-2017, xamarin-studio

If I use a current Version of Xamarin Studio with updated Mono Framework, am I able to use all features of the new C# 7.0 version in Visual Studio 2017 or where can I find a summary of supported features by Xamarin?

Comment: XS/VS4m w/ Mono 5.x+ uses Roslyn/'csc' compiler vs. Mono's original `mcs`, xbuild has also been updated to also use `csc` (but is being replaced with msbuild) so all current C#7 features are available:   http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#c-compiler